# delayed_job like queue for python

Tags: python, ruby, queue, message-queue

I need a queue to send data from ruby to python

The system is an application with a Ruby frontend and python backend and I'd rather not add another complicated piece. If it was ruby only I'd just go with delayed_job, but ruby->python is harder.

So

I'm looking for a **simple** database based queue (similar to delayed_job) for python for which I'm planning to hack a ruby 'producer' part.

Or just surprise me with a solution I haven't think of yet.

Comment: What do you have against a real message queue like RabbitMQ which has native Ruby and native Python drivers?

Comment: RabbitMQ would be good, or just simply creating a queue in a MySQL or Postgres DB.

Comment: "creating a queue in a MySQL or Postgres DB" isn't usually as simple as using a message queue.

Comment: I'm not against real queues, its just that I don't think I need anything complicated right now. installing and managing RabbitMQ does take time (all servers and developer machines on 2 operating systems) and I like the simplicity of db based solutions like delayed_job. For ruby there are several such solutions, I'm looking for a similar for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could have a look at [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

Comment: looked at it, but it doesn't look very simple ;) multiple backends and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but just for anyone stumbling across this question now and looking for a simple answer that isn't Celery:

[django-background-tasks](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks) is  based Ruby's DelayedJob.

> Django Background Task is a databased-backed work queue for Django,
>   loosely based around Ruby's DelayedJob library. This project was
>   adopted and adapted from this repo.
>
> To avoid conflicts on PyPI we renamed it to django-background-tasks
>   (plural). For an easy upgrade from django-background-task to
>   django-background-tasks, the internal module structure were left
>   untouched.
>
> In Django Background Task, all tasks are implemented as functions (or
>   any other callable).
>
> There are two parts to using background tasks:
>
> ```
> creating the task functions and registering them with the scheduler
> setup a cron task (or long running process) to execute the tasks
> ```